# Designing a wireless sensor algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

So I'm given a sorted array containing n >= 2 number of integers. These integers are used to represent wireless sensors and each has a broadcast radius of 2, meaning that if I had a number "4" it can reach at most "2" or "6". So I need to design an algorithm that returns an array containing all pairs of sensors (as subarrays) that can communicate with each other, possibly having their message forwarded by some intermediate sensor, eg. "8" is able to communicate with "12" given "10" exists in the array. The algorithm also needs to run in O(n^2) time.

So at first it was pretty simple, I would just get the length of the array, n, and iterate through it using a while loop (i < n) and if the current element + 2 was greater or equal to the following element, add its index and the following element's index to a subarray and add it to an empty array. But I was having problems with the intermediate sensor part. How would I find the intermediate sensor connections though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sort the list (takes `O(NlogN)` time)
2. Start traversing the array
3. See if the current element can communicate with our current set. If yes, then add it to the set and continue. Else, store the old set, create a new one and add current element to it.
4. For each set, generate all pairs of sensors that can communicate.

Something like:

```py
def generate_pairs(array):
    pairs = []
    array_length = len(array)
    for i in range(0, array_length):
        for j in range(i+1, array_length):
            pairs.append([array[i],array[j]])
    return pairs

main_list = [1,2,4,7,9,10,13]
main_list.sort()
curr_set = [main_list[0]]
all_sets = []
for i in range (1,len(main_list)):
    if main_list[i]-main_list[i-1] <=2:
        curr_set.append(main_list[i])
    else:
        all_sets.append(curr_set)
        curr_set = [main_list[i]]

all_pairs = []
for i in all_sets:
    all_pairs += generate_pairs(i)

print(all_pairs)
# prints [[1, 2], [1, 4], [2, 4], [7, 9], [7, 10], [9, 10]]
```